# How to replace getColumnModel() function - EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm new to EXTJS. I didn't find getColumnModel() in EXTJS4.

Here is my code snippet:

grid.getColumnModel().on('hiddenchange', this.verifyLayout, this, {delay:1});

How can I replace the same in EXTJS 4?

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance!

Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

In Ext JS 4 `Ext.grid.Panel` have [`columnhide`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-columnhide) and [`columnshow`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-columnshow) events which you can use instead of Ext JS 3 `Ext.grid.ColumnModel` `hiddenchange` event.
So you can rewrite your code like this:

```
grid.on('columnhide', this.verifyLayout, this, {delay:1});
grid.on('columnshow', this.verifyLayout, this, {delay:1});
```

Also if your `verifyLayout` method process event parameters you will have to modify it.